# Failed to resolve: com.facebook.react:react-native:0.61.5 in Android project

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, build.gradle

I am developing an android library in which i need to use ReadableArray, WritableArray, ReadableMap which are part of com.facebook.react:react-native library.
I have added `com.facebook.react:react-native:0.61.5` in build.gradle of the library module but gradle sync fails with error: `Failed to resolve: com.facebook.react:react-native:0.61.5`  . what to do to solve this issue?

build.gradle of library module:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.cam_library'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles "consumer-rules.pro"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
        dataBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

    //react
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:0.61.5"
}

afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {
            release(MavenPublication) {
                from components.release

                groupId = 'com.github.dev-ooo'
                artifactId = 'Watch-Cam-Library'
                version = '0.1.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

build.gradle of project:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.0' apply false
}
```

settings.gradle of project:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        maven { url "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2" }
    }
}
rootProject.name = "WatchCam"
include ':app'
include ':cam-library'
```

Comment: Try upgrading to 0.71.0-rc.0 https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/facebook/react/react-native/

Comment: @KenWolf still same error is happening with the version you mentioned:  Failed to resolve: com.facebook.react:react-native:0.71.0-rc.0

Comment: remove this line from settings.gradle: `repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)`